# How to pass field values of custom model to Qweb report?

Tags: python, xml, odoo

I have created a wizard in that i placed a many2one field [names] from another model in which report printing is enabled. What is happening here is when i select one record & clicked on print button it is printing only empty report.so is it possible to fetch the data into report over here.

```
 def print_report(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):

    ob=self.pool.get('book.room')
    wizard=self.browse(cr,uid,ids,context=context)


    datas = {
         'ids': wizard.name,
         'model': 'book.room',
         'form': ob.browse(cr, uid, wizard.name)#[-1]
         # 'form': [{'create_uid': (1, u'Administrator'), 'create_date': '2015-10-20 10:32:42', 'name': (1, u'Nani'), '__last_update': '2015-10-20 10:32:42', 'date_end': '12/10/2015', 'date_start': "13/12/1201", 'write_uid': (1, u'Administrator'), 'write_date': '2015-10-20 10:32:42', 'display_name': u'Nani', 'id': 18}]
    }

    print datas.get('form')

    # print datas,'88888888888888'
    # print datas['form'],'9999999999999'

    return {
        'type': 'ir.actions.report.xml',
        'report_name': 'hotel_mng.Booking_Details',
        'datas': datas,
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 class print_report(osv.TransientModel):
_name='report.wizard'
_columns={
    'room1':fields.many2one('hotel.allroom','roomnum','Room No.')
}
    def print_report(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
        current=self.browse(cr,uid,ids)
        obj=self.pool.get('book.room')
        k=obj.search(cr,uid,[('name','=',current.name.name)],context=context)


    context = {}
    data = self.read(cr, uid, ids)[0]


    datas = {
    'ids': k,
    'model': 'report.wizard',
    'form': data,
    'context':context
    }
    return{
        'type' : 'ir.actions.report.xml',
        'report_name' : 'hotel_mng.Booking_Details',
        'datas' : datas,
        } 

print_report()
```

the above code is working fine for me.. it takes names from ref. model and prints report Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
def print_report(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
        datas = {}
        a=[]
        print "---------------------------------------------------------------"
        for phone in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context):
            b=phone.selection_item
        print b
        if context is None:
            context = {}
        datas['ids'] = context.get('active_ids', [])
        datas['model'] = context.get('active_model', 'ir.ui.menu')
        datas['value']=b
        context.update({'names':b})
        return {

        'type': 'ir.actions.report.xml',
        'report_name': 'sales_invoice.report_mom',
        'datas': datas, 
        'context':context}
```

at report

```
<p align="right"><span t-esc="o._context['names']"/></p>
```